# Is there any way to automate a page through different regions of the world using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

For example i block my site for Pakistan.Then how do i automate from Pakistan end,to check whether my site is blocked or not .

Answer (score 0):

We used TOR for this case via silvertunnel lib https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.silvertunnel-ng.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

import net.freehaven.tor.control.TorControlConnection;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //Connecting to TOR's control port
    //TOR must be running and following line must be added to the torrc:
    //ControlPort 9100
    Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9100);
    TorControlConnection conn = TorControlConnection.getConnection(s);
    //no authentification at the moment
    conn.authenticate(new byte[0]);

    //write some changes to torrc (like setting exit node)
    //ExitNodes {US}
    //StrictExitNodes 1


    //send "RELOAD" signal - reloading torrc from disk
     conn.signal("RELOAD");
  }
}
```

And these files: https://github.com/guardianproject/jtorctl

It was long time ago so I have no more code but here are a couple of links for reference:

1. http://www.yasith.me/2017/01/selenium-webdriver-with-tor-network.html
2. https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/652/how-to-call-tor-browser-using-selenium-using-java